# Как отправить POST-запрос c cookes

Tags: python-3.x

В python новичок не ругайте сильно

нужно с помощью python отправить запрос на сайт игры поискав в гугле нашёл библиотеку request   вроде как можно отправить POST запрос
 requests.post('url', data)

но на сайте нужна авторизация как отослать запрос с  cookes

то что мне нужно работает с этим скриптом

```
$.ajax({
    url        : 'https://academy.galaxy.bipgame.io/api/movement/trade/2634208/',
    type       : 'POST',
    data       : {"quantity":{"5":10000}},
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

как отправить такой запрос с python и с  cookes

Answer (score 0):

```
cookies = {'name': 'value'}

r = requests.post('http://your-url.gov', cookies=cookies)
```